# Possible memory leak with CTLineRef?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a memory leak in my code that I'm having trouble solving. Specifically, I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) at this line:

```
CGFloat xStart = origin.x + CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex(line, index, NULL);
```

in the following code:

```
- (CGRect)firstRectForNSRange:(NSRange)range;
{
    NSInteger index = range.location;

    NSArray *lines = (__bridge NSArray *) CTFrameGetLines(self.textFrame);
    NSInteger linesCount = [lines count];
    CFIndex paragraphSpacingOffset = (self.paragraphSpacing > 0) ? 1 : 0;

    for (NSInteger i = 0 + paragraphSpacingOffset; i < (linesCount - paragraphSpacingOffset); i++)
    {
        CTLineRef line = (CTLineRef) CFBridgingRetain([lines objectAtIndex:i]);
        CFRange lineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line);
        NSInteger localIndex = index - lineRange.location;

        if (localIndex >= 0 && localIndex < lineRange.length)
        {
            NSInteger finalIndex = MIN(lineRange.location + lineRange.length, range.location + range.length);

            CGPoint origin;
            CTFrameGetLineOrigins(self.textFrame, CFRangeMake(i, 0), &origin);
            CGFloat xStart = origin.x + CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex(line, index, NULL);
            CGFloat xEnd = origin.x + CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex(line, finalIndex, NULL);
            CGFloat ascent, descent;
            CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, NULL);
            CFRelease(line);
            return CGRectMake(xStart, origin.y - descent, xEnd - xStart, ascent + descent);
        }
        else
        {
            CFRelease(line);
        }
    }

    return CGRectNull;
}
```

I'm almost certain it's a memory leak as I've checked the code thoroughly. Can anyone see how I'm mismanaging the Core Foundation object `line` above? Is something happening when `line` gets sent to `CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex` that I need to release it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly here:

```
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(self.textFrame, CFRangeMake(i, 0), &origin);
```

This says "write the line origins from index `i` through the end of the end of the frame into the memory pointed to by `origin`." Unfortunately, `origin` points to just a single element, so you're going to walk all over the rest of your stack. I suspect you mean `CFRangeMake(i, 1)`.

Other notes:

You're creating a lot of complexity here moving between CFArray and NSArray. the code would be a lot simpler if you just use CFArray:

```
CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(self.textFrame);
CFIndex linesCount = CFArrayGetCount(lines);
...

  CTLineRef line = (CTLineRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, i);
```

Doing it this way, you don't need any calls to `CFRelease()`. The only reason you're calling `CFRelease` now is because you're calling `CFBridgingRetain()`, which is making everything more complicated than it needs to be. Sometimes getting over to NSArray is a really great thing, but in this case it isn't.

Comment: Thanks Rob, you're a life saver as usual.